# ORA-600 [32695] [hash aggregation can't be done]

Tags: oracle, aggregation, oracle-data-integrator

I have a mapping that is deployed in Production but I'm getting below error in the insert new row step of my mapping:

> ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [32695], [hash aggregation can't be done], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

Same mapping was in Staging but no errors. What can be the cause? I have a MIN function in one of my date columns.

Comment: `ORA-00600` typically means you need to call Oracle support

Answer (score 1):

Hash aggregation errors are bugs that you may be able to avoid through a hint, session setting, or parameter change.

When disabling Oracle features, try to affect the smallest possible scope:

1. If possible, add a `/*+ no_use_hash_aggregation */` hint to the query. If you can't directly modify the query, you could add the hint through a SQL Profile.
2. If the query changes all the time and doesn't have a single SQL_ID, change the session with `alter session set "_gby_hash_aggregation_enabled" = true;`.
3. If you can't change the session settings, change the entire system with `alter system set "_gby_hash_aggregation_enabled" = true;`. (Insert standard undocumented parameters warning here.)

ORA-600 errors are bugs, but there's usually no need to panic about them. The first step for ORA-600 errors is to go to support.oracle.com, search for the "ora-600 tool", enter the first parameter value ("32695"), and look at the different documents. Always do that simple step before creating a service request or calling Oracle, otherwise you might waste a lot of time. And keep in mind that you often don't need to "fix" these errors with patches, upgrades, or other serious changes. There's usually a simple way to avoid the problem and only spend a few minutes on it.

Luckily, this specific problem is not only hidden behind the Oracle support paywall, there are many other search results that recommend disabling hash aggregation. When grouping or joining data, hashing is usually faster than sorting (because a hash can be done in one operation, and a sort is done in LOG(N) operations). Oracle used to always sort the data for grouping, but in more recent versions has started to use hashing instead. Unfortunately the "HASH GROUP BY" operations still have some problems and occasionally need to be manually disabled.